# With limited memory, how can I export very long Print results into a PDF or a notebook file?

Tags: export, printing

I have a script with a long loop and very long formatted outputs like the following example code:

```
Do[Print[Style[Table[RandomReal[], {30}, {15}] // MatrixForm, Blue]], {10000}]
```

In order to display all the output in the desired format and save them into `*.nb` or `*.pdf`, at least 2GB memory is needed, which exceeds the available upper limits of x86 OS.

How can I export the formatted results immediately into a `*.nb` or a PDF file so that the code does not demand so much computer memory?

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for editing it!

Comment: As an aside, I would point out that `RandomReal` can produce matrices, so your example can be reduced to `Do[Print[Style[RandomReal[1., {30, 15}] // MatrixForm, Blue]], {10000}]`.

Comment: How do you expect to use the output? The file produced, whether .nb or .pdf, will too big, to open in _Mathematica_ on your system.

Comment: I'm missing something. If you put 10000 large styled matrices into a PDF file, that file will be big.

Comment: Yes, the PDF file will be big; but usually less than 50M and requires very small memory to view it.

Comment: Export[] also supports PDF format, maybe I can try to Export them into many PDF files and then combine them together; however there is no documents on how to export special format or even Append something into existing PDF file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11680/discussion-between-m-goldberg-and-lcfactorization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not generate a notebook with 10000 30 x15 matrices without the *Mathematica* front-end eating up a good deal more then 2 GB of memory. Best I have done so far is create and save a notebook file with 2500 such matrices. On my system, this used up about 800 MB of *Mathematica* front-end memory. The good news is that it was done with one line of code:

```
CreateDocument @ Table[Style[RandomReal[1., {30, 15}] // MatrixForm, Blue], {2500}];
```

After saving the newly generated matrix notebook, I quit *Mathematica*, and then restarted it again by double-clicking on the matrix notebook's icon. The matrix notebook loaded quickly and only used about 4 MB of front-end memory. Using the File > Print... menu items, I was able to create a PDF file with two matrices per page (trying to put more on a page made the numbers too small for comfortable reading).

You asked in chat, how this approach could be modified to handle the case where each matrix generated has a dependency on an iteration variable `n`. Suppose this dependency was scalar multiplication by `n`. In this case, `n` would simply be the first element in the in the iteration control list, the second argument of `Table`:

```
CreateDocument @ Table[Style[n RandomReal[1., {30, 15}] // MatrixForm, Blue], {n, 2500}];
```

Should you adopt this approach, I recommend doing it with a freshly launched front-end session.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also tried to "output.pdf"~Create~CreateDocument@ Table[Style[n RandomReal[1., {30, 15}] // MatrixForm, Blue], {n, 2500}]; but Create[] function does not make any pagebreak; unless we handle binary PDF creation operation, this should be the best way to create good looking formatted PDF output.

Comment: @LCFactorization. To get page breaks, image scaling, and other layout controls, I had to use _Mathematica_'s notebook printing tools. On my system, OS X, the print dialog offers "Save as PDF" as an option, so after formatting the notebook for printing, I took advantage of that option.